# Downloading a file using multiple connections from a single server

Tags: networking, downloads

I am using aria2c to download a single file using multiple connections (two) from the same source. The command I am using `aria2c -x2 <source url>` as the default for maximum concurrent downloads is 5 and split's default is also 5.

But still its showing only one download connection and sometimes even if it starts with 2 connections, later its reverting to one connection.

Any insights would be helpful

EDIT : [Started with 2 connections and went to 1 connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lok0m.png)

Comment: maybe the server doesn't allow more than 1 connection? For me, with your command, `aria2c` shows `CN:2`.

Comment: Sometimes its reverting to 1 connection before the whole file is downloaded. 
But I need to download the whole file using two simultaneous connections.

Comment: @RoVo The server allows more than one connection. For sometime its downloading with the help of 2 connections but not the whole file

Answer (score 1):

The man page says that `-x` changes the maximum connections, but mentions that `-k` is used to specify the chunk sizes:

> Download a file from one host using multiple connections
>
> $ aria2c -x2 -k1M "http://host/file.zip"
>
> NOTE:
>
> The -x option specified the number of allowed connections, while the -k option specified the size of chunks.

Then the `-k` option says:

> -k, --min-split-size=
>
> aria2  does  not split less than `2*SIZE` byte range.  For example, let’s consider downloading 20MiB file. If `SIZE` is 10M, aria2 can split file into 2 range `[0-10MiB)` and `[10MiB-20MiB)` and download it using 2 sources(if --split >= 2, of  course).   If  SIZE is 15M, since 2*15M 20MiB, aria2 does not split file and download it using 1 source.  You can append K or M (1K = 1024, 1M = 1024K).  Possible Values: 1M -1024M Default: 20M

It's possible the target file is too small to be split.

Also possible is that the target HTTP server is not capable of providing "chunked" downloads, which you can likely determine using the `--console-log-level=debug` flag.t

Comment: I have gone through this part of man page

Comment: Have you tried running the download with the debug logging?

Comment: I have done it and this is the link for the log file
https://drive.google.com/open?id=18b5wvzIXUehvg83fST9-K8rejI_gnRxc

There is time out happening. Is it because of this that the connection count is going down by one. But this is the third instance of timeout in the whole log file. (This is only part of log file where the connection count is going down)

Comment: It's very possible the remote server has banned you for making too many connection attempts.

Comment: No, the server accepts multiple connections for sure. Otherwise why it would start with 2 connections in first place and it goes for around 25% of file download